# Spring Security 3.1.3 Issues

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am using Spring Security **3.1.3.RELEASE** in my maven pom because the book am reading is 2013 and that is what they used and have the following code snippets:

**// AdminController**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin")
public class AdminController {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/movies")
    @ResponseBody
    public String createMovie(@RequestBody String movie) {
        System.out.println("Adding movie!! "+movie);
        return "created";
    }
}
```

**// LoginController**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("")
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(method= {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST}, value="/custom_login")
    public String showLogin() {
        return "login";
    }
}
```

**// web.xml**

```
 <web-app>
      <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

      <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml</param-value>
      </context-param>

      <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
      </filter>
      <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      </filter-mapping>

       <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
      </listener>

      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>terrormovies</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>terrormovies</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

**// Spring security Config :: applicationContext-security.xml**

```
<security:http auto-config="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**/*" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <security:form-login login-page="/custom_login"  username-parameter="user_param" password-parameter="pass_param"/>
    </security:http>
    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service>
                <security:user authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" name="admin" password="admin" />
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
```

**//login.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Terror movies</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="/j_spring_security_check" method="POST">
        Username<input type="text" name="user_param"/><br/>
        Password<input type="password" name="pass_param"/><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
        </form>
    </body>
    <% if(request.getParameter("error") != null){
            out.println("ERROR LOGIN");
        }
    %>
</html>
```

When I start my application I get the login page with the form alright. I enter admin/admin as username/password respectively. When i click on the login button I get this error page saying:

```
Problem accessing /admin/movies. Reason:

    Request method 'GET' not supported

Powered by Jetty://
```

instead of going to the method `createMovie(@RequestBody String movie)` in the 
`AdminController`.

The address of this error page is :: `http://localhost:8080/admin/movies`

The LoginController and AdminController are in the same package.

What am I missing here?

### Updated

In the form action:: `<form action="/j_spring_security_check" method="POST">`,
where does "/j_spring_security_check"` leads to? I think that is where the problem is. Am beginner in Spring Security so I can't figure it out now. I did a search but not any good answer.

Comment: @J-Alex The code i have posted is all what i have.

Comment: What is the proper scenario? Where should user/admin be redirected after successful login? As I can see you don't have a page for that.

Comment: @J-Alex The form has a "POST" method. So i expect it to go to createMovie(@RequestBody String movie) in the AdminController. But like i said in my UPDATED section, i don't know where "j_spring_security_check" points to. It is the action-URL but i don't know the value it contains

Comment: @J-Alex Ok if i have to do redirect, how should i do it? Am Spring Security beginner so i'm still grabbing the concepts. It seems to me that "j_spring_security_check" makes sure the form is validated and afterwards there has to be redirect. Can you help me how to do the redirect because it is not in the book am reading. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The error response message you are receiving tells you exactly what the problem is:

> When i click on the login button i get this error page saying::
>
> ```
> Problem accessing /admin/movies. Reason:
>
>    Request method 'GET' not supported
>
> Powered by Jetty://
> ```

And in your controller you have set this method:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin")
public class AdminController {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/movies")
    @ResponseBody
    public String createMovie(@RequestBody String movie) {
        System.out.println("Adding movie!! "+movie);
        return "created";
    }
}
```

And just as the message says, the `/admin/movies` method is mapped just for `POST` requests, so a `GET` request which is what is generated on redirection from the login success cannot be handled.

So here the trouble is not really the `spring-security` config, the problem is just that after login you are making a request to a `request-mapping` annotated method which does not support `GET` requests.

To solve it you could just configure this method into the existing `AdminController`:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/movies")
public String createMovieForm() {
    return "createMovieForm";
}
```

And create a jsp with a `form` which points to the `POST` mapped controller method:

```
<form action="/admin/movies" method="POST">
    Movie<input type="text" name="movie"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>
```

I would be easier too if you delete the @RequestBody annotation in the `POST` method, so finally the `AdminController` should end like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin")
public class AdminController {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/movies")
    @ResponseBody
    public String createMovie(String movie) {
        System.out.println("Adding movie!! "+movie);
        return "created";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/movies")
    public String createMovieForm() {
        return "createMovieForm";
    }
}
```